# Tag for text content in html

Tags: input, tabs, styles, html

I wanna know what is the best HTML tag element to content literal text in order to give any text format.

I was using SPAN tag in order to assign the style of width but it doesn't work.

**I want to give the behavior of tabulation because there are many fields like a contact form**

```
<span style="width:100px;">MY TEXT</span><input type="text" value=""/>
```

But it's not working.

Yeah, I know if I was starting a new project I could define a CSS to create forms inside form legend and div's but what I want is something specific right now.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `SPANS` are inline and `DIVS` are block level ..  You will be able to to this using `DIVS` with the float property --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , may be `display: inline-block` will help you in your specific case:

```
<span style="width:100px; display: inline-block; ">MY TEXT</span><input type="text" value=""/>
```

Comment: @MaximusDecimus , great , so may be it will be interesting for you: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility for "tabular" look:  Of course you will want to give them uniform widths so that they remain aligned with each other etc .. But this basically is the drift ..

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">MY TEXT1: <input type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div style="float:left;">MY TEXT2: <input type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div style="float:left;">MY TEXT3: <input type="text" value=""/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">MY TEXT4: <input type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div style="float:left;">MY TEXT5: <input type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div style="float:left;">MY TEXT6: <input type="text" value=""/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see your point but... what happens if your text is different. i.e.: My text 1 = bla bla bla bla <input type="text">
My text 2 = bla bla <input type="text">
My text 3 = bla bla bla <input type="text">